# What Raw Read Error Rate Is Acceptable After 1 Year Power On?

Tags: ssd

Anyone used an SSD for over a year and want to share their Raw Read Error Rate, so I can compare my numbers?

My current Raw Read Error Rate is 118 total ECC and Raise Error

With over 180 million hardware read errors in a year

Various tools says my disk is fine and at 99% health - is that realistic?

Comment: My Intel SSD have no such value at all.

Comment: Strange. Go download HD Tunes (trial) and check it out

Comment: I have the same concerns. Using HD TunePro to test my SSD I get 92 million errors in less than a month. They have been all corrected and HD TunePro says everything is OK. I'm wondering if it's not a bad cable issue

Answer (score 1):

Need more information, like your drive model, etc., the program you used to get such information, and so on.

Without that, simply "comparing" values won't do any good, because we can't be sure what we're comparing.

Take a look at [this site](http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=94079) and [this other one](http://www.hdsentinel.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=1386) to see people discuss that you can't use the raw numbers some programs report, instead of that you should use just the diagnostic of the manufacturer.

Comment: Indeed, the value has no well defined meaning.

Comment: I'm using OCZ Vertex 2 and used HD Tunes, The OCZ tool to get the information